# IOS app crashes: Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, mobile-development, ios-app-group

I am facing an issue while I am returning after some time in the App, can anyone help me in this regard?

Please find the below crash log.

I did some research regarding this issue & I found some questions in StackOverflow and GitHub, but as I am pretty new in React Native/App development I am unable to figure out the way and steps to resolve the issue.

**Crashlytics**
[image]

**Crash log**

```
Date/Time:           2020-06-03 21:50:48.8370 +0400
Launch Time:         2020-06-03 21:50:22.7923 +0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.51.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, process-exit watchdog transgression: application<com.bankonus>:5046 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 5.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-exit | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.840 (user 1.840, system 0.000), 18% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.002, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192f7e77c 0x192f58000 + 157564
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192df50a8 0x192df3000 + 8360
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192df4fe8 0x192df3000 + 8168
3   companyName                     0x0000000104331b2c 0x1041b0000 + 1579820
4   companyName                     0x0000000104373990 0x1041b0000 + 1849744
5   companyName                     0x00000001043738f0 0x1041b0000 + 1849584
6   companyName                     0x0000000104371d80 0x1041b0000 + 1842560
```

**Symbolicated crash log:**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  3

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x193e945f0 __exceptionPreprocess + 224
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193bb6bcc objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x193d98ea8 -[NSObject+ 192168 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 139
3   CoreFoundation                  0x193e98694 ___forwarding___ + 1315
4   CoreFoundation                  0x193e9a5bc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 91
5   bankonus                        0x102cbd968 0x102ba0000 + 1169768
6   bankonus                        0x102cbe120 0x102ba0000 + 1171744
7   CoreFoundation                  0x193e9a760 __invoking___ + 143
8   CoreFoundation                  0x193d6bb40 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 299
9   CoreFoundation                  0x193d6c718 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 75
10  companyName                         0x102cef840 0x102ba0000 + 1374272
11  companyName                         0x102cf1950 0x102ba0000 + 1382736
12  companyName                         0x102cf16b4 0x102ba0000 + 1382068
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x193b599a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x193b5a524 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x193b068a4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 607
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x193b07294 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 415
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x193b1078c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 587
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x193babb74 _pthread_wqthread + 271
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x193bae740 start_wqthread + 7
```

Comment: Your app was killed by the watchdog because it spent too much time on the main thread. Symbolicate your crash log to determine where it is spending time.

Comment: actually, I am unable to figure out which code part is creating the problem, can you please make it a bit clear to me?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log to turn the hex values into a line number in your source code.

Comment: I have added the symbolicate crash log at the last in my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, i see this happening with almost every app on my Air 2 running 13. In 12 it was fine. Something’s changed in 13 that causes the OS to terminate these apps